# how to assign hidden field value to variable without submitting in php

Tags: php

```
**<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My site</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="hidden" name="myTest" value="10">
    <?php
        $val = $_GET['myTest'];
        echo $val;
    ?>
</body>
</html>**
```

How can I assign the value of hidden field to PHP varaible?.. without submitting any form (on runtime)

Comment: This sounds like a job for JS rather than PHP. PHP is a server side language, which means that all PHP code will be executed on the server, way before the HTML (including your input) even reaches the client (browser). For PHP to be able to read that value, you will need to send the value from the client to the server (like submitting the form).

Comment: However, if the value in the input is hard coded, like in your example, then you can hard code it in the PHP variable as well: `$val = 10;`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Javascript for this(especially to get data from the input fields that are hidden from the user). Php is a server side language, best use is at the backend, not in doing the frontend tasks.

The Code is:

**Javascript**

```
<input type="hidden" name="myTest" value="10">
<script>
    var t = document.querySelector("input[name=myTest]")
    document.write(t.value);   
</script>
```

`document.write` writes the given data in the web page as a string.
[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write).

Now if you want to sent this data to the backend part(say to the server), then

**Javascript**

```
<script>
function httpGetAsync(theUrl, data, callback){
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
            callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true); // true for asynchronous 
    xmlHttp.send(data);
}

var t = document.querySelector("input[name=myTest]");
httpGetAsync('test.php', JSON.stringify({data: t})) //This will send data in a json format.
</script>
```

**Php**. Make a file named *test.php* and its content is:-

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
   $data = file_get_contents('php://input'); //To recive json based data.
   $obj = json_decode($data, true);
   var_dump($obj);
?>
```

This should work..